# Slow Remote Debugging with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

When I 'm remotely debugging an executable, I have it available in the remote machine along with its (500 MB) PDB.

When I start the remote executable, the local Visual Studio takes a LOT of time to finally run it - the messages about DLL's attaching are going super slow in the output window. Debugging is also slow when the app is finally responsive after attaching.

It's like as if it's trying to exchange some debugging information back and forth with my PC, although the EXE and PDB are there.

Is there anything I can do to speed up this? I 've even placed the remote folder for msvsmon to find in tools -> options -> debugging -> symbols.